# Need Help To Get Matched Values From Table 1 to Table 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

Please Help me to Get Matched Values From Table 1 to Table 2 based on formula's
The table to needs to be filled by ref values based on the associate marked attendance.

I have tried `V lookup()` and `Match()` Nothing worked out.

[image]

Comment: The better question is why in Table 2 rows 4-8 are all blank

Comment: That needs to be filled with same format, ntng mean in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry ! Guys ! Self Found an Answer Just Now. I used it earlier but forgot it.

Just Now  Remembered again.

The Value can be Get Through `Countif()` Function. and It it's HD Then `Countif()*.5`

> If anyone know's other methods please post here so that will get some
>   idea's in easier way